# Sort CCnode or NSObject into a NSMUtableArray

Tags: nsmutablearray, cocos2d-iphone, nssortdescriptor

I would like to sort a NSMutableArray.

I don't know how to sort an object.

in ActionScript I can use the sort method like : arr.sortOn("x", Array.NUMERIC);

I can't use NSSortDescriptor and the method. I can't find an example with all sort methods.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For iOS4 or later, [sortUsingComparator:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method is easy to use. sorting CCNode with Y position.

```
[array sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)^(CCNode *node1, CCNode *node2) {
    float y1 = node1.position.y;
    float y2 = node2.position.y;
    if (y1 < y2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (y1 == y2)
        return NSOrderedSame;
    else
        return NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```